# Как сделать табы с помощью data и id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Всем привет. Помогите пожалуйста сделать табы. Мне надо чтобы по клику на `.type-button`, к котором я приписал data, скрывались блоки, id которых не совпадает с `data-category .type-button`. Я думаю что это можно сделать на Jquery, но не представляю себе логику.

```js
$('.type-button').click(function() {
  // 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-category="All projects" class="type-button">All projects</span>
<span data-category="Logotypes" class="type-button active">Logotypes</span>
<span data-category="Mobile" class="type-button">Mobile</span>
<span data-category="Polygraphy" class="type-button">Polygraphy</span>
<span data-category="Webdesign" class="type-button">Webdesign</span>
<!--Блоки, которые мне надо скрывать по клику на type-button:-->

<div class="projects-list">
  <a class="project-banner" rel="bookmark" id="All projects"></a>
  <a class="project-banner" rel="bookmark" id="Logotypes"></a>
  <a class="project-banner" rel="bookmark" id="Mobile"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.type-button').click(function() {
    $('.project-banner')
      .hide()
      .filter('[id="' + $(this).data('category') + '"]')
      .show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-category="All projects" class="type-button">All projects</span>
<span data-category="Logotypes" class="type-button active">Logotypes</span>
<span data-category="Mobile" class="type-button">Mobile</span>
<span data-category="Polygraphy" class="type-button">Polygraphy</span>
<span data-category="Webdesign" class="type-button">Webdesign</span>

<div class="projects-list">
  <a class="project-banner" rel="bookmark" id="All projects">All projects</a>
  <a class="project-banner" rel="bookmark" id="Logotypes">Logotypes</a>
  <a class="project-banner" rel="bookmark" id="Mobile">Mobile</a>
</div>
```

Из-за особенностей парсера jQuery строка `#All projects` будет расценена как "найти элементы `projects`, которые являются дочерними к элементу с `id=All`. Поэтому в фильтре был использован селектор поиска по атрибуту

Еще есть вариант написания такого обработчика

```
$('.type-button').click(function() {
  $('.project-banner').hide();
  $(document.getElementById($(this).data('category')).show();
});
```

В  этом случае элемент с указанным id будет искаться по всему документу, а не только среди коллекции с классом `.project-banner`. Учитывая, что стандарт требует, чтобы у элементов атрибут id был уникален, то для валидного HTML результат будет такой же. Но первый вариант все-таки лучше читается

Comment: Спасибо, я обратил внимание. Извините если вопрос глупый, но почему с пробелами в дате и в id, фильтр не работает ? И есть ли способ это обойти ?

Comment: @Kek отредактировал ответ

Answer (score 1):

Суть должна быть следующей - у вас в блоке и кнопке нужно иметь какие-то уникальные характеристики чтобы идентифицировать что эта кнопка соответствует именно этому блоку. Лучше всего для этого подойдут именно data-* атрибуты.

А уже схема скрытия и открывания их следующая: по умолчанию у вас все блоки скрыты, это прописывается им в стилях. Нужно еще обозначить некий класс, который вы будете добавлять блоку чтоб его показать. В итоге при нажатии на кнопку вы у текущего активного блока убираете этот класс, а у блока с таким же data-* атрибутом как и у кнопки которую вы нажали вы пропишите этот класс.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.type-button', function(){
    let cat = $(this).data('category');
    
    $('.category.shown').removeClass('shown');
    $('.category[data-category="'+cat+'"]').addClass('shown');
});
```

```css
.type-button{
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    background:lightgrey;
    padding:5px 15px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.category{
    display: none;
    border:1px solid black;
    background:white;
    padding:60px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.category.shown{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-category="All projects" class="type-button">All projects</span>
<span data-category="Logotypes" class="type-button active">Logotypes</span>
<span data-category="Mobile" class="type-button">Mobile</span>
<span data-category="Polygraphy" class="type-button">Polygraphy</span>
<span data-category="Webdesign" class="type-button">Webdesign</span>


<div class="category" data-category="All projects">
  All projects
</div>
<div class="category" data-category="Logotypes">
  Logotypes
</div>
<div class="category" data-category="Mobile">
  Mobile
</div>
<div class="category" data-category="Polygraphy">
  Polygraphy
</div>
<div class="category" data-category="Webdesign">
  Webdesign
</div>
```